# password-less ssh works to connect to one user on a remote machine but not another

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

The remote server is running CentOS 5.5.

I have created an rsa key from my client server, and copied it into `/home/hadoop/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  This worked fine - I can ssh to `hadoop@remoteserver` without being prompted for a password.

I also have a `data` user on remote server that I want to ssh into.  I copied the exact `authorized_keys` file over to the data user's home directory, but cannot ssh in.  I believe the permissions are set correctly - when I do `ls -al` in `/home/data/.ssh` on the remote server, it shows:

```
drwx------  2 data data 4.0K Dec 20 12:52 .
drwxrwxr-x 26 data data 4.0K Dec 20 12:52 ..
-rw-------  1 data data  405 Dec 20 12:58 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 data data  736 Oct 24 17:18 id_dsa
-rw-r--r--  1 data data  607 Oct 24 17:18 id_dsa.pub
-rw-------  1 data data 1.7K Dec 20 10:51 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 data data  399 Dec 20 10:51 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 data data 5.2K Dec 20 10:40 known_hosts
```

Is there anything I'm overlooking? Any advice is much appreciated.

EDIT: Does the user's group matter at all? (I would imagine not, since permissions are 0 for group, but thought it may be relevant).  data user is in a different primary group:

```
$ id data
uid=1350(data) gid=1350(datausers) groups=1350(datausers)
```

However, I just tried `cd ~/; chown -R data:datausers .ssh`, and it still asks me for a password when I try to ssh in.

EDIT2:

```
$ ssh -vvv data@remote-server
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to remote-server [192.168.5.208] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/data/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/data/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/data/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/data/.ssh/id_dsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/data/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: loaded 3 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 129/256
debug2: bits set: 522/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/data/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/data/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug1: Host 'remote-server' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/data/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 523/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
 debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/data/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/data/.ssh/id_rsa (0x2aef897453e0)
debug2: key: /home/data/.ssh/id_dsa (0x2aef897454a0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 192.168.5.208.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/data/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/data/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/data/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering public key: /home/data/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
data@local-server's password:
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide verbose output:  ssh -vvv data@server

Comment: Also, keep in mind... just because it works on server A & is properly configured on server A... does not imply that server B is configured for key-based authentication.

Comment: @TheCompWiz - Sorry if that was unclear, there is only one remote server.  Just trying to (passwordlessly) ssh in as a different user on that server.

Comment: Well... honestly, I do this every-day.  The only 2 bits are a) public key in authorized_keys in users' home dir, b) ssh user@host.  It's not that complicated.  You may need to check the "auth" log for more information.

Comment: @kubanczyk - added the verbose output

Comment: Looks like the client is doing everything right. Try again, then check `/var/log/auth.log` (might be named slightly different depending on your system) for any failure messages, particularly messages related to `/home/data/.ssh/...`

Answer (score 1):

How was your ssh key created? Appears the key file may not be in a proper format.

```
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/data/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Perhaps something was bungled in the copy paste. I would need to check the docs but SSH keys I use typically do not have BEGIN lines.

Comment: I'll try re-generating the RSA1 key when I get a chance tomorrow.  Curious that it might work with one user and not another, but if those warnings aren't normal I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using local `/home/data/.ssh/id_dsa` to match the remote `/home/data/.ssh/authorized_keys`. This means you've attempted to ssh from user `data` to user `data`.

When you've successfully connected to `hadoop` (using `/home/hadoop/.ssh` remotely) have you used local `/home/data/.ssh/id_dsa` (user `data`) or some other local user?

Comment: I've used /home/data/.ssh/id_rsa - so the local data user.  Literally just a matter of `ssh data@remote-server` vs `ssh hadoop@remote-server`, both when I am the data user on local server.

Comment: No idea. Compare proper logs with ssh -vvv hadoop@remote-server  maybe there would be some difference that would give you a clue.